# the result skips towards the word request scanner

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Ariete25Programs {
public static void main(String[] tin) {

char again = 0;
int choose;
if(choose == 7) {
char again7 = 0;

do
{
    System.out.println("---Vowels and Consonants---");  

    String line;
    System.out.println("Enter word: ");
    line = sc.nextLine();

    String vowels = " ", consonants = " ", digits = " ", spaces = " ";

        for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); ++i)
        {
            char ch = line.charAt(i);
            if(ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i'
                || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u' || ch == 'A' || ch == 'E' || ch == 'I'
                || ch == 'O' || ch == 'U') 
    {
                vowels+=line.charAt(i);
        }
            else if((ch >= 'a'&& ch <= 'z')) 
    {
                consonants+=line.charAt(i);
           }
    }
    System.out.println("Vowels: " + vowels);
    System.out.println("Consonants: " + consonants);

        System.out.println("Try Again? (Y/N)");
        again7 = sc.next().charAt(0);
        if(again7 == 'n') {
        System.out.println("Menu? [y/n]");
        again = sc.next().charAt(0);
        }
        else if(again7 == 'n') {
        System.out.println("Thank you for using the programs!");
        System.exit(0);
        }
        }
        while(again7 == 'y');
```

then the result when you choose 7 becomes like this
-----Vowels and Consonants-----
Enter word:
Try again?(Y/N)

can someone help me? I can't seem to figure out the problem in my codes. It keeps on skipping.

Comment: I think you're going to need to describe your problem better. This is quite vague.

Comment: the code works but the result isn't what I wanted it to be. The scanner for entering the word doesn't seem to work, it just skips.

Comment: It's only possible to help if you specify all inputs, the output and your intended output.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you do something like `choose = sc.nextInt();` you should try `choose = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());`
Please replace `sc.next().charAt(0)` with `sc.nextLine().charAt(0)`.
Documentation:

- [Scanner.next()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--)
- [Scanner.nextLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--)

Moreover `else if(again7 == 'n')` is wrong since you already did the same check few lines before, so you'll never execute the code in that `else if` block

```
        do
        {
            System.out.println("---Vowels and Consonants---");  

            String line;
            System.out.println("Enter word: ");
            line = sc.nextLine();

            String vowels = " ", consonants = " ", digits = " ", spaces = " "; // digits and spaces are not used

            int end = line.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < end; ++i) {
                char ch = line.charAt(i);
                if(ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i'
                        || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u' || ch == 'A' || ch == 'E' || ch == 'I'
                        || ch == 'O' || ch == 'U') {
                    vowels += line.charAt(i);
                }
                else if ((ch >= 'a'&& ch <= 'z')) {
                    consonants += line.charAt(i);
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Vowels: " + vowels);
            System.out.println("Consonants: " + consonants);

            System.out.println("Try Again? (Y/N)");
            again7 = sc.nextLine().charAt(0);
            if (again7 == 'n') {
                System.out.println("Menu? [y/n]");
                again = sc.nextLine().charAt(0);
                if (again == 'n') {
                    System.out.println("Thank you for using the programs!");
                    break;
                } else {
                    // display Menu
                }
            }
        } while(again7 == 'y');
```